# Internet Explorer 9 Developer Tool Network Traffic View Empty Progress Bar

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I try to debug an issue with my asp.net forms web site. When the web site is idle for 29 minutes, I pop up a message showing count down from 60 and asking the user that session would expire, do you want to continue the session. Pop up shows up at right time, but when count down hits 0 second, it is supposed to navigate to the login screen, but the browser gets stuck trying to make the redirection. On the tab I see the spinning circle. I checked network traffic from developer tools. When the redirection happens, the request appears, but the bar that shows time taken starts up empty and then it is filled by yellow color. Does anyone know what empty bar means?

Comment: How are you redirecting to the login, can you post that code snippet?

Comment: By using document.location. This problem occurs when session time out is set to 30 minutes. If it is set to 2 or 3 minutes then it works fine.

Comment: Just to confirm - since you're using popup - your redirection code is something like `opener.location.href = 'http://url..'` ? Can you update your post with actual code snippet?

Comment: document.location = <%= QuotedTimeOutUrl %>;

Comment: What happens if instead of `document.location` you'd use `location.href`? Also it's a better idea not to use <%= %> in this case, either use a hardcoded URL if you know it in advance Or pass it as a parameter to JS function Or save it in advance in a hidden field.

Comment: I don't see why <%= %> is bad. At the end whether you hard code or do the way I do, the browser gets the same value. What you say is not related to the problem.